# Get commits from master branch to a branch with different history

Tags: git, github, heroku, deployment, branch

I'm making an E-commerce website using django and web(HTML/CSS/Js).

I'm planning to host the app on **Heroku**, so for that, I'll need to create some files and do minor changes in the project directory, which are just for heroku, and not the project itself.

I'm maintaining a **master** branch which will be updated more often.

For *heroku*, I'm planning to create a different branch named **heroku** or something, that will contain the *heroku* related files and changes.

What I want to do is

1. Whenever I make any commits to the *master* branch, I want to get the commits from it to the *heroku* branch.
2. The commits I make to the *heroku* branch shouldn't be related or reflected in the *master* branch (provided, I'll only make changes to the heroku specific files, and not the common files).

How can I achieve this functionality?

Currently I only have master branch on my git repo and remote repo.

The **heroku** branch will just be present for live site, and main changes will be made on master.

I'm new to heroku, and I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way, but that is not by git CLI.

I use VsCode for editing my code. The folder is a git repo, so vscode automatically gives features of git.

I created a branch named **heroku** besides my **master** branch and published the branch to my remote.

Now, my remote has the branches, **heroku** and **master**.

I made changes to **heroku** branch and pushed it to the remote.
I made different changes to **master** and pushed it too.

Now my repo has different file histories for both my branches.
In order to get the changes from **master** to **heroku**, I opened **VsCode**, went to **Git** section, then from options, I clicked on **Pull from**, then selected **origin** and then **origin/master**.

By doing this, the changes from master reflected on **heroku** branch locally. Now, I had to push the changes.

This works for all the files, even the ones which have different file histories on both branches!
Only the changes that are made on **master** are pulled, and files are not replaced on **heroku** branch, hence, its a really effective method!

Comment: The process that you are doing manually in vs code under git section can be automated using github actions. That's what I explained in my answer.

Comment: Ok.. I'll try that! Thnks

Answer (score 1):

You can try GitHub actions (or bitbucket pipelines) for ci-cd and create a pipeline for master branch that merges master branch to your new branch.

You can follow [this Link](https://medium.com/@karlstad/create-a-github-actions-workflow-that-auto-merges-the-master-back-to-dev-branch-8b1ebe7009b3) for auto-merging a pull request using github action.

[This Link](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2021/10/17/github-actions-workflows-for-automatic-rebasing-and-merging/#:%7E:text=with%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20rebase-,Automatic%20merging,-If%20you%20would) can also be helpful.

Comment: Didn't get a single point!

Comment: which number, I have 2